DJANGO ImportError: cannot import name 'url' from 'django.conf.urls' version 5.0.3
I'm following this DJANGO Rest Framework tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eA4H3p95hbM&list=PLmDLs7JbXWNjr5vyJhfGu69sowgIUl8z5&index=4
After modifying in 'urls.py', then type "python manage.py migrate" I get this error:

from django.conf.urls import url
ImportError: cannot import name 'url' from 'django.conf.urls' (F:\Learning HTML and CSS\DJANGO_DAVE GRAYE.venv\Lib\site-packages\django\conf\urls_init_.py)

 urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root = settings.MEDIA_ROOT)


I have search solution for this error. But they are working on DJANGO version 4.0 above and my current version is 5.0. I try follow their solution but it seems not working in my case

django.conf.urls.url() is removed in Django 4.0. Remove the line from django.conf.urls import url

django.conf.urls.url() has been deprecated in Django 3.1 and is removed in Django 4.0.
Remove the line from django.conf.urls import url.

Not helpful. What shoud one use instead?
